# how can you grant read-only access to the K8s dashboard?

Tags: kubernetes

I've tried creating a cluster role that only has access to view pods, however, for some reason that account can still see everything; secrets, deployments, nodes etc. I also enabled skip-login, and it seems like by default anonymous users don't have any restrictions either.

**Service account:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
name: sa-example
namespace: default
```

**Cluster Role:**

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: cr-example
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] 
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

**Cluster Role Binding:**

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: crb-example
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  name: cr-example
  kind: ClusterRole
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: sa-example
    namespace: default
```

**Context:**

```
K8s version: 1.17.3
Dashboard version: v2.0.0-rc5
Cluster type: bare metal
authorization-mode=Node,RBAC
```

Answer (score 1):

How did You check if it works or no?

I made a reproduction of your issue with below yamls

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: sa-example
  namespace: default

---  

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: cr-example
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]        

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: crb-example
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  name: cr-example
  kind: ClusterRole
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: sa-example
    namespace: default
```

And I used [kubectl auth can-i](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#checking-api-access) to verify if it works

```
kubectl auth can-i get pods   --as=system:serviceaccount:default:sa-example
yes
kubectl auth can-i get deployment   --as=system:serviceaccount:default:sa-example
no
kubectl auth can-i get secrets   --as=system:serviceaccount:default:sa-example
no
kubectl auth can-i get nodes   --as=system:serviceaccount:default:sa-example
no
```

And it seems like everything works just fine

The only thing which if different in my yaml is

```
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: cr-example instead of cr-<role>
```

So it actually match ClusterRoleBinding

I hope it help you with your issues. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: My ClusterRole also matches the ClusterRoleBinding, "cr-<role>" was just a typo in the question. When I use "kubectl auth can-i" to verify the sa permissions the output is always yes.


For example:
kubectl auth can-i get secrets --as=system:serviceaccount:default:sa-example
yes

Comment: Hi @Gaby, do have have any other cluster roles created which might gave your service account access to other resources than pods? Maybe there are some issues with your cluster? I have tried it, both on gke and kubeadm v1.17.3 and it's working.